# Which version of this gem am I using?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I updated the `shopify_api` gem in my gem file to this:

```
gem 'shopify_api', '~>4.9'
```

When I do `gem list` I get

```
shopify_api (4.9.0, 4.3.2, 4.0.7)
```

When I do `bundle show shopify_api` I get

```
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/shopify_api-4.9.0
```

In my `Gemfile.lock` I have the following entries

```
shopify_api (4.9.0)
  activeresource (>= 3.0.0)
  rack
shopify_app (7.2.8)
  omniauth-shopify-oauth2 (~> 1.1.11)
  rails (>= 4.2.6)
  shopify_api (>= 4.3.2)
```

My question is which version of the `shopify_api` gem am I using? And is there a definitive way to find out?

Comment: You're using 4.9.0. You can run `bundle` without any arguments to see what is being used.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `gem list` command shows you *all* versions of the gem installed. As the `gem` tool doesn't have any way of knowing which you're using it can't tell you. All it can do is install, uninstall, or reinstall gems.

The `bundle show` command *will* tell you which one is being used as per your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` settings.